# Keep an inner div fixed when the outer div is transformed

Tags: css, transform, scaletransform

On the web page I'm working on, I'm scaling a div to fit on certain viewports. One of the inside divs has fixed positioning in order to keep it at the top when scrolling within the div.

```
<div id='a'>
    <div id = 'b'>This should be fixed</div>
    <div id = 'c'>normal</div>
    <div id = 'd'>normal</div>
</div>
```

However, after scaling the div using CSS transform, it no longer stays at the top of the page. Any ideas on what to do or explanation why this happens?

```
#a{
    height: 2000px;
    transform-origin: 0% top;
    transform: scale(0.96, 0.96);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% top;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.96, 0.96); 
}
#b{
    position: fixed;
}
```

I provided a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/pkoq8ctj/

Answer (score 0):

I feel like if it's fixed it doesn't need to be inside the other div. Here's a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanjsfiddle00/pkoq8ctj/1/

```
<div id = 'b'>This should be fixed</div>
<div id='a'>
    <div id = 'c'>normal</div>
    <div id = 'd'>normal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if, I had to transform a table and keep the first row of the table position fixed?

Comment: Idk that you can do that without javascript. Maybe on resize you remove that table row and stuff the contents into a fixed div.